# puppeteer headless browser crashes after running out of memory

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, wavesurfer.js

I'm using `wavesurfer` to generate `sepctrograms` of `wav files` and then save them with the `screenshot()` function.  The thing is i need to destroy the `wavesurfer instance` and create a new one every time i load a new `wav file`. Otherwise the `waveforms` will stack and cause the crash.

This is how my code is structured :

```
for(waveFile in waveFiles){
  page.evaluate((){
   // create wavesurfer instance generate the spectrogram and 
  // return getBoundingClientRect of the div surrounding the spectrogram 
  //to take a screenshot of it
  })
  page.screenshot()
 //afterwards i need to destroy the wavesurfer instance
}
```

i tried passing the waveform instance and destroying it in a new evaluate() but it didn't work. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You need to use asynchronous await for these.

Comment: Without `await` your ` page.evaluate()` and ` page.screenshot()` make many tasks in parallel which may consume many resources.

Comment: i'm doing that actually ! the problem is in the wavesurfer instance that needs to be destroyed after the screenshot is taken. But i don't know how to do that in an other evaluate so i ended up closing the page and opening an other one in the next iteration which solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do you try to launch a browser with flag **--disable-dev-shm-usage** ?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage']
});
```

Base on [document](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#tips) from puppeteer:

> By default, Docker runs a container with a /dev/shm shared memory
> space 64MB. This is typically too small for Chrome and will cause
> Chrome to crash when rendering large pages. To fix, run the container
> with docker run --shm-size=1gb to increase the size of /dev/shm

Comment: i saw that ! but i'm not using docker. either way i can't let the browser use a lot of memory since i'm going to deploy the function in the cloud. I ended up closing the page and opening another one for every spectrogram i generate. It decreased memory usage from 1.6 GB to 90MB . I don't think it's the optimal solution but it works for the time being